# AJAX PHP, on button click pass variable from javascript prompt to php script to set cookie?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

newbie here. i'm experimenting with ajax and php lately just for learning purposes, i have this simple html:

```
<button type="button" id="setc">Set Cookie</button>
```

on click i want to ask for a variablename and value so i could pass it on my php script, here's my js code:

```
$("#setc").click(function(){
    var cookieVar = prompt("Enter a cookie variable","");
    var cookieVal = prompt("Enter the variable's value","");
    $.ajax({
        url:'setcookie.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "cookieVar="+cookieVar+"&cookieVal="+cookieVal,
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus+errorThrown);
         }
    });
});
```

and here's my php script:

```
<?php
    $cookieVar="";
    $cookieVal="";
    echo setcookie($cookieVar,$cookieVal);
?>
```

but when i clicked the button it gives me this error:

"**Warning**:  Cookie names must not be empty in **D:\xampp\htdocs\phpcustomsite\setcookie.php** on line **4**"

how can i make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Four issues I can think of, all with PHP:

1. Your PHP script tries to use `$cookieVar` and `$cookieVal` without declaring them.  PHP has no idea what these are
2. `setcookie` tries to set http headers. `echo` tries to output content to the browser.  You cannot set headers after you've output content (unless you have some buffer settings allowing this). This is probably not a problem in this case (since the inner function runs first), but to be safe I would set the cookie first, then echo on a separate line.
3. `setcookie` doesn't return the cookie value, so if you're trying to get that with `echo setcookie(...)` it won't work.  That function returns `true` if the cookie is successfully set, and `false` otherwise.
4. Only use the PHP closing tag `?>` if you intend to send content to the browser -- some HTML -- *after* it.  Using a closing tag otherwise increases the possibility of unwanted spaces and line returns (whatever comes after) to be sent to the browser.

Modify your PHP to:

```
<?php
//capture values sent by the browser
$cookieVar = $_POST['cookieVar'];
$cookieVal = $_POST['cookieVal'];

//set cookie and send result
if(setcookie($cookieVar,$cookieVal)===true){
    echo "Successfully set cookie $cookieVar to $cookieVal";
}
else{
    echo "Failed to set cookie $cookieVar to $cookieVal"
}
```

Notice, no closing `?>`.

Comment: @Twirlman You're welcome. If my answer helped solve your problem, please select it (and upvote if you like).

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax, it's better to use:

```
 $.ajax({
    url:'setcookie.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {cookieVar: cookieVar,
           cookieVal:cookieVal
    },...
```

And your php setcookie.php.
Do like BeetleJuice tell you..

Comment: I think `jQuery.ajax` will accept a query string as the value of `data`. It doesn't have to be an object.  From the docs "Type: PlainObject or String or Array. Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string". Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use data with differents ways, but it's better, faster and clearly like this.

Comment: But you the OP's way was wrong.. I thought `wrong` goes too far since the docs say that it's ok, that's why I commented.

Comment: I've try an ajax with the same kind of data than Twirlman used... and It don't work if the variable have space. If I use the array, it's works!!

Comment: That's a good point The other way didn't work for you because the query arguments need to be uri encoded (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376172/ajax-not-fully-posting-data-to-php-file/38376277#38376277).  When you use object notation, `jQuery` does it for you.  So the other way isn't wrong, but what you suggested is much easier to use :-)